# How can I clean (reset cache) of React Native using Expo. Not sure if it is cache issue

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-start

I am building a simple React Native app with create-react-native-app using only react-navigation and base-64(base 64 encode/decode) as dependencies. Over time starting the app became slower and now sometimes it is getting stuck(waiting for about 30min) on "Starting packager..." after running NPM start.

I've tried starting it with "npm start -- --reset-cache" but nothing changed

Once it is up and running I don't get any error or warning in DevTools or terminal. Also there are no issues with the performance of the app

What can I do to make NPM start smooth and quickly as before? Are there any general steps I can take to troubleshoot this issue?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-devtools": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Official Documentation [clearing bundler caches](https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-windows/)

Answer (score 280, accepted):

`expo r -c`

According to [this forum post](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-react-native-packager/1352) from an Expo dev, that's the command to start it cache clean

EDIT: They have changed it from `exp r -c` to `expo start -c`

Comment: `exp` is now `expo`, `r` is short for `start`, and `-c` is short for `--clear`

Comment: what if I don't want to start expo and just clean the cache?

Comment: @kwoxer none of the above will remove actual React Native cache

Comment: based on the new npx method, it is now ``npx expo start -c``

Answer (score 50):

The command to run is:

> expo r -c

Answer (score 12):

For **Expo 45** and below

```
expo r -c
```

For **Expo 46** and above

```
npx expo start --clear
```

Comment: npm start --reset-cache just gave me the error:
There was a problem loading the project. This development build encountered the following error. Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Answer (score 6):

In you console run:

```
expo start
```

After the QR code is shown, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 5):

I was running `expo build:ios` and needed to clear the cached provisioning profile. I did so with:

```
expo build:ios --clear-provisioning-profile
```

To see the full list of commands that clear specific elements from the cache, run `expo build:ios --help`

Comment: Is expo build:ios --clear-provisioning-profile the same as expo start --clean?

Answer (score 4):

**--clear-cache** is a flag to clear cache before the build:

```
eas build -p android --clear-cache
eas build -p ios --clear-cache
```

all available flags, commands etc. you can see by input command:

```
eas build --help
```

Answer (score 2):

`npm start -c` or `npx expo start -c`

Answer (score 1):

### 2023 update

```
npx eas build -p ios --clear-cache
```

or

```
npx eas build -p android --clear-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

It will clear the cache and start the project
expo start -c