# Environment variable not being set in Axios configuration on Expo React Native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use a `.env` file inside my Expo project root directory with an API URL for Axios requests in a file called `axios.ts`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const Axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
});

Axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

export default Axios;
```

In order to make it work, I installed the `dot-env` library as suggested [by the official Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/#using-a-dotenv-file)

Here is my `package.json`

```
  {
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "start-expo": "expo start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "1.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.61.23",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.2.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.8",
    "jest-expo": "~38.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Of course, I also set the `babel.config.js` file

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    plugins: ['inline-dotenv'],
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

The problem occurs when I am making an API call to some endpoint.

```
import Axios from "../../api/axios";
const login = async () => {
  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
  try{
   const response = await Axios.post(ENDPOINTS.login,{
        email,
        password,
        device_id
      });
      console.log(response);
    }catch(e){ //TODO : deal with errors
      console.log(e);
    }
 };
```

The request is getting a `404 error` when using the `.env` file and working normally if I just set the string directly.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const Axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://myurl..." // This is working as expected!
});

Axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

export default Axios;
```

It seems that the `.env` file is not being set correctly but according to the `console.log()`, it has the correct value. I suspect the reason is that the environment variable is set after the Axios function is called, so at first it's null but then when the log appears it is already set.

Is my explanation plausible or what other setting might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it out the next day, I was surprised that it was working fine so I am assuming there was some problem with the cache. For anyone facing this problem, I suggest [deleting the cache in Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998636/how-can-i-clean-reset-cache-of-react-native-using-expo-not-sure-if-it-is-cach) and try again