# Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Pls anyone help me how to fix this error  "ERROR  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'."
i have tried many things like deleting node modules npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types but nothing works for me how can i fix now
[image]

## package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

## babel.config.js

```
module.exports = { presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'], plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], };
```

Comment: this is due to unupdated libraries, you need to remove them or update them yourself...
Btw this is an error only on react-native 0.69 and above so you can also downgrade your project react-native version.

Comment: @lmasneri
 what will the solution of it pls tell solution step wise

Comment: The solution would be to find the deprecated library, in the error it is mentioned where the error is.
And the other solution is to downgrade to react-native 0.68.3 using the react-native upgrade helper (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

Comment: @lmasneri not working i have tried

Comment: it still does not work without any 3rd party library ?

Comment: @lmasneri i dont know what you mean

Comment: It is not working because one of the package you have in your package.json is outdated and not up to date from the maintainers. The only solution is to remove this package. The error message provide path to the file.

Comment: @lmasneri still not working i have tried everything

Answer (score 3):

You will need to check all of the downloaded dependencies in the node_modules folder which contains the following import statement.

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
```

Change it imports from `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` manually.

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Comment: same error again i have removed import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native'; in my every file to import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';

Comment: You could try type the following command in the command prompt to clear cache. `cd android && gradlew clean`

Comment: For more information, you may try to read the post here.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33734#issuecomment-1242387033

Comment: its a expo app i cant cd andriod

Comment: Since I am not familiar with expo, you may find something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998636/how-can-i-clean-reset-cache-of-react-native-using-expo-not-sure-if-it-is-cach) and try.

Comment: if you dont mind can i get your email i will mail you my project you can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248253/discussion-between-justforhelp-and-peter-tam).

Comment: have you found any solution? I am also facing the same issue, searched in node_modules and no lib was using it, we are using It in only 1 file and updated it, tried ./gradlew clean for android. nothing works and showing the same error in both android and iOS.

Comment: This solution will need to be done every time `node_modules` gets generated, consider using `patch-package` to keep the changes

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kiuQ's answer, `react-native-progress-circle` is most likely the problem here. It has been deprecated, and the ViewPropTypes is a known issue in that package.

Remove it from your project, or simply replace it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-circle-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Just like @kiuQ said above, you need to first install deprecated-react-native-prop-types:

`npm i deprecated-react-native-prop-types`.

Then after that, find where the error is on the terminal click its link to find where the `ViewPropTypes` was imported. Remove it and import it on its own like this:

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from "deprecated-react-native-prop-types"
```